# Covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

Suppose you have $$\nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu f$$ with $f$ a scalar function. Suppose that you know the expression for $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu f$. Is it possible to do calculate the 4 covariant derivative expression as follows?

$$\nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu f=(\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta-\Gamma^\eta_{\alpha\beta}\partial_\eta)\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu f.$$

Comment: Yes. That's correct, because $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu f$ is a scalar.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.